# Temporary non-const istream reference in constructor (C++)

Tags: c++, constructor, pass-by-reference

It seems that a constructor that takes a non-const reference to an istream cannot be constructed with a temporary value in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Bar
{
public:
   explicit Bar(std::istream& is) {}
};

int main()
{
   istringstream stream1("bar1");
   Bar bar1(stream1); // OK on all platforms

   // compile error on linux, Mac gcc; OK on Windows MSVC
   Bar bar2(istringstream("bar2"));

   return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine with MSVC, but not with gcc.  Using gcc I get a compile error:

```
g++     test.cpp   -o test
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘Bar::Bar(std::istringstream)’
test.cpp:9: note: candidates are: Bar::Bar(std::istream&)
test.cpp:7: note:                 Bar::Bar(const Bar&)
```

Is there something philosophically wrong with the second way (bar2) of constructing a Bar object?  It looks nicer to me, and does not require that stream1 variable that is only needed for a moment.

**EDIT**:  In response to Johannes Schaub's comment I'd like to give a bit more context.  First, this is not the first time I have been annoyed by this behavior of C++, so I am genuinely interested in the higher level philosophical discussion of this issue.  That said, in this particular case I have a class that reads in a file that contains data used to construct the object.  I also like to write automated tests that use a string instead of the file.  But using the file for construction is the primary use case.  So I decided to make a constructor that takes an istream, so I could use either a file(stream), or a string(stream).  That is how I got here.  My test programs construct objects directly from strings, to simulate reading files.  This saves me the trouble of creating separate data files for each little test.

Comment: You may pass `istringstream("bar2").seekg(0)` as a workaround.

Comment: The MSVC behavior is a non-standard extension which produces a warning, and I think if you enable standards mode (/Za) you'll get an error there too.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub:  Very clever.  I suppose any method that returns a reference to the temporary object would work here.

Comment: yeah exactly. It's a silly hack :) I wonder what the constructor is used for, tho? Maybe folks can find some better way to do it? Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just how C++ works currently: you cannot bind non-const references to temporary objects.  MSVC is non-standard in allowing this.

C++0x will have r-value references and change things around a bit here.  There are various philosophical interpretations people have tried to apply—for both sides of the issue—but I haven't found one that is wholly convincing.  It seems more of "you just have to pick one behavior and stick to it", which explains both current C++ and 0x's changes: the chosen behavior has shifted.

Comment: Are you saying that the construct "Bar bar2(istringstream("bar2"));" will work in the next C++ standard?  That would be nice.

Comment: @Christopher, you will need to overload the constructor like `explicit Bar(std::istream&) { .. } explicit Bar(std::istream&&) { .. }`. Then the first will grab all lvalues (mostly variables), and the second grabs all rvalues (mostly temporaries like yours).

Comment: Almost, I'm saying you can make it work, as Johannes shows, but not that your current code will magically work in 0x.

Comment: Well then, he can solve the immediate problem with an overloaded constructor accepting a `const istream&` and `const_cast` ing it away. RR's would make it cleaner and avoid capturing truly const streams but not easier or "more possible."

Comment: @Potatoswatter, sadly that is not possible since streams are not copyable (binding a temporary to a const reference requires the temporaries class to have an accessible copy constructor).

Answer (score 1):

Roger is right… this is a generic policy of C++ that only const references may bind to temporaries. I don't think rvalue references would help you, though, because in the case of passing a non-temporary stream you *do* want to continue using its modified state.

More to the point, why not replace the constructor with a `friend` extractor `istream &operator>>(istream &s, Bar &b)`? At the cost of adding an uninitialized state to the object, the syntax would be even more C++-ish.

Comment: That uninitialized state is one of the reasons I dislike iostreams.

Comment: the implicit object parameter is allowed to bind to temporaries. (`op>>(int&)` is a member function). Try reading into a `char[N]` - it should fail since i think it is a free operator (not a class member).

Comment: @Johannes: oh yeah, of course, it's just confusing again with the juxtaposition with `istringstream("") >> my_string` not working. Thanks.