# std::ostringstream printing the address of the c-string instead of its content

Tags: c++, stream

I have stumbled on a weird behavior that I just could not explain at first (see [ideone](http://ideone.com/DSPmM)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Reference     : "
            << (void const*)"some data"
            << "\n";

  std::ostringstream s;
  s << "some data";
  std::cout << "Regular Syntax: " << s.str() << "\n";

  std::ostringstream s2;
  std::cout << "Semi inline   : "
            << static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(s2 << "some data").str()
            << "\n";

  std::cout << "Inline        : "
            << dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream&>(
                 std::ostringstream() << "some data"
               ).str()
            << "\n";
}
```

Gives the output:

```
Reference     : 0x804a03d
Regular Syntax: some data
Semi inline   : some data
Inline        : 0x804a03d
```

Surprisingly, in the last cast we have the address, and not the content!

Why is that so ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The expression`std::ostringstream()` creates a temporary, and `operator<<` which takes `const char*` as argument is a free function, but this free function cannot be called on a temporary, as the type of the first parameter of the function is `std::ostream&` which cannot be bound to temporary object.

Having said that, `<<std::ostringstream() << "some data"` resolves to a call to a member function which is overloaded for `void*` which prints the address. Note that a member function can be invoked on the temporary.

In order to call the free function, you need to convert temporary (which is rvalue) into a lvalue, and here is one trick that you can do:

```
 std::cout << "Inline        : "
            << dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream&>(
                 std::ostringstream().flush() << "some data"
               ).str()
            << "\n";
```

That is, `std::ostringstream().flush()` returns `std::ostream&` which means, now the free function can called, passing the returned reference as first argument.

Also, you don't need to use `dynamic_cast` here (which is slow, as it is done at runtime), for the type of the object is pretty much known, and so you can use `static_cast` (which is fast as it is done at compile-time):

```
 std::cout << "Inline        : "
            << static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(
                 std::ostringstream().flush() << "some data"
               ).str()
            << "\n";
```

which should work just fine.

Comment: Exact! Took me an hour to figure it out :x I've posted my investigation below... and somehow wish I had ask earlier (though it would not have been as educative).

Comment: Wow! Your workaround is neater than mine. Definitely one of those days when I want to bash Stroustrup on the head for ruling out binding to non-const :x

Comment: @MatthieuM. : Kerrek and I had a small discussion on this. If you're interested, [read the comments here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116808/read-integers-from-a-text-file-with-c-ifstream/8116840#comment9981318_8116840) (the comments on my answer). There are other work around as well, but using `flush` is better than the rest.

Comment: I don't get this line *as the type of the first parameter of the function is std::ostream& which cannot be bound to temporary object.* . Can you express the sentence in easy words?

Comment: @FreakEnum: You **cannot** write this : `A & a = A()`, as the expression `A()` creates a temporary object of type `A`, but non-const reference (on the left-side of assignment) cannot be bound to the temporary, according to the language specification. But once you make it a const reference, then the binding is possible; that is, you **can** write this : `A const & a = A()`. Similarly, `std::ostream&` is a non-const reference which cannot be bound to the temporary object created out of the expression `std::ostringstream()`.

Comment: @FreakEnum: For more detail, you can read this topic : [Temporary non-const istream reference in constructor (C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405871/temporary-non-const-istream-reference-in-constructor-c)

Answer (score 9):

A temporary cannot bind to a reference to non-const formal argument.

Therefore, the non-member `<<` is not picked up.

You get the `void*` version instead.

C++11 fixes this by adding a non-member **rvalue stream inserter** function,

> **C++11**
>   **§27.7.3.9 Rvalue stream insertion**
>   [ostream.rvalue]
>   `template <class charT, class traits, class T>
>
>   basic_ostream<charT, traits>&
>
>   operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, traits>&& os, const T& x);`
>   1 *Effects:* `os << x`
>   2 *Returns:* `os`

Comment: Ah thanks for this, I didn't know they had solved the issue in C++11. It's incredible how adding the rvalue references/move semantics simplifies life.

Comment: @Matthieu: Sadly, [other subtle issues](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8828973/500104) crept in because of these, and it seems there is no really satisfactory solution for these nasty temporary streams.

Comment: @Xeo: yes, already saw (and upvoted) these :) I really like the defect Howard linked to (well, its proposed resolution at least).

Comment: add a reference that contains discussion [1203. More useful rvalue stream insertion](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue1203)

Answer (score 4):

To get the started, the simplest solution is to get the list of possible overloads that the compiler considered, for example [trying](http://ideone.com/0DKfc) this:

```
X x;
std::cout << x << "\n";
```

where `X` is a type without any overload for streaming which yields the following list of possible overloads:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:21: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << x’
include/ostream:112: note: candidates are: std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))
include/ostream:121: note:                 std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&))
include/ostream:131: note:                 std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&))
include/ostream:169: note:                 std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(long int)
include/ostream:173: note:                 std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(long unsigned int)
include/ostream:177: note:                 std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(bool)
include/bits/ostream.tcc:97: note:         std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(short int)
include/ostream:184: note:                 std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(short unsigned int)
include/bits/ostream.tcc:111: note:        std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(int)
include/ostream:195: note:                 std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(unsigned int)
include/ostream:204: note:                 std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(long long int)
include/ostream:208: note:                 std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(long long unsigned int)
include/ostream:213: note:                 std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(double)
include/ostream:217: note:                 std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(float)
include/ostream:225: note:                 std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(long double)
include/ostream:229: note:                 std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(const void*)
include/bits/ostream.tcc:125: note:        std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>*)
```

First scanning this list, we can remark that `char const*` is conspiscuously absent, and therefore it is logical that `void const*` will be selected instead and thus the address printed.

On a second glance, we note that all overloads are *methods*, and that not a single free function appears here.

The issue is a problem of reference binding: because a temporary cannot bind to a reference to non-const, overloads of the form `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,X)` are rejected outright and only member functions remain.

It is, as far as I am concerned, a design bug in C++, after all we are executing a mutating member function on a temporary, and this requires a (hidden) reference to the object :x

The workaround, once you understood what went awry, [is relatively simple](http://ideone.com/1Ar56) and only requires a small wrapper:

```
struct Streamliner {
  template <typename T>
  Streamliner& operator<<(T const& t) {
    _stream << t;
    return *this;
  }

  std::string str() const { return _stream.str(); }
  std::ostringstream _stream;
};

std::cout << "Inline, take 2: " << (Streamliner() << "some data").str() << "\n";
```

Which prints the expected result.