# Is it possible to save a memory address to a string?

Tags: c++

Say I have an object

```
MyObj stuff;
```

To get the address of stuff, I would print

```
cout << &stuff << endl; 0x22ff68
```

I want to save 0x22ff68 in a string. I know you can't do this:

```
string cheeseburger = (string) &stuff;
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why would you try to do something like this in first place?

Comment: To know if I've seen a particular object before. Does it matter?

Comment: It matters because what you are trying to do is nonesense really.

Comment: If you "want to know if you've seen an object before" you'd just ... keep the memory address handy. Why would you convert it to a string?

Comment: It's complicated and I'm not posting a whole API on stack overflow :)

Comment: Better post it or some people will assume they know better.

Comment: @a fish who swims around, I experience this with every question I post on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [std::ostringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287188/stdostringstream-printing-the-address-of-the-c-string-instead-of-its-content).

But don't expect the address you have to be really meaningful. It could vary from one run to the next of the same program with the same data (because of [address space layout randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), etc.)

Comment: I understand that. It only needs to be correct for current run. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Here's a way to save the address of a pointer to a string and then convert the address back to a pointer. I did this as a proof of concept that `const` didn't really offer any protection, but I think it answers this question well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // create pointer to int on heap
    const int *x = new int(5);
        // *x = 3; - this fails because it's constant

    // save address as a string 
    // ======== this part directly answers your question =========
    ostringstream get_the_address; 
    get_the_address << x;
    string address =  get_the_address.str(); 

    // convert address to base 16
    int hex_address = stoi(address, 0, 16);

    // make a new pointer 
    int * new_pointer = (int *) hex_address;

    // can now change value of x 
    *new_pointer = 3;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try using a string format

char strAddress[] = "0x00000000"; // Note: You should allocate the correct size, here I assumed that you are using 32 bits address

sprintf(strAddress, "0x%x", &stuff);

Then you create your string from this char array using the normal string constructors