# Is this an instance of a reference-to-non-const binding to a temporary?

Tags: c++

<sub>**Disclaimer:** This question is for understanding. I'll use `boost::lexical_cast` in the field. [It *has* sort of come up in the real world in places, though.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6094/a-version-of-operator-that-returns-ostringstream-instead-of-ostream)</sub>

---

Take [the following attempt](https://ideone.com/XfMFOx) at an "inline" lex-cast approach:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::string s = static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(
       std::ostringstream() << "hi" << 0
    ).str();
    std::cout << s;
}
```

The result is something like `0x804947c0`, because the `operator<<` that works with `"hi"` is a free function whose LHS must take `std::ostream&`<sup>†</sup>, and temporary `std::ostringstream()` can't bind to a ref-to-non-`const`. The only remaining match is the `operator<<` that takes `const void*` on the RHS<sup>††</sup>.

Now [let's swap the operands](https://ideone.com/cHUQUP):

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::string s = static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(
       std::ostringstream() << 0 << "hi"
    ).str();
    std::cout << s;
}
```

The result is `"0hi"`.

This mostly makes sense, because the `operator<<` that takes `int` is a member function of base `ostream`<sup>†††</sup> and, as such, is fine with being invoked on the temporary. The result of that operation is a reference to the `ostream` base, to which the next `operator<<` is chained, i.e. read it as `(std::ostringstream() << 0) << "hi"`.

But why then does *that* operation on `"hi"` go on to yield the expected result? **Isn't the reference on the LHS still a temporary?**

---

<sub>Let's focus on C++03; I'm told that the first example may actually work as "intended" in C++11 due to the catch-all operator for rvalues.</sub>

<sup><sup>†</sup> `[C++03: 27.6.2.1]: template<class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<charT,traits>&,charT*);`</sup>

<sup><sup>††</sup> `[C++03: 27.6.2.1]: basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(const void* p);`</sup>

<sup><sup>†††</sup> `[C++03: 27.6.2.1]: basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(int n);`</sup>

Comment: I guess the answer is something along the lines of "the rules for binding temporaries to references are nowhere near that simple; here are the pertinent phrases".

Comment: This works for the same reason that you can write a function template `template <typename T> T& lvalue(T&& v) {return v;}` in order to bind non-const lvalue references to temporaries.

Comment: Wouldn't the overloads for your first footnote be the ones that take `const char[T]*`? (Not that it changes anything.)

Comment: @Mankarse: Oops - this should all be about C++03.

Comment: @Mat: I'm not aware that any exist? And certainly not as members, which is the point here. :)

Comment: The same principle applies in C++03. You can write a member function `T& ref() {return *this;}` which can called on temporaries to allow the creation of lvalue references to them. (It is only the expression that results in the temporary that is an `rvalue`, `lvalues` to the same object can still be created).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::ostringstream printing the address of the c-string instead of its content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287188/stdostringstream-printing-the-address-of-the-c-string-instead-of-its-content). Got caught by this a year ago or so... stupid non-binding rule :(

Comment: @Mankarse: I think the last sentence of your previous comment is the answer that I've been looking for

Comment: @MatthieuM.: It's a kind of reverse duplicate, in that I'm well aware of the reason for the "address gets printed behaviour", but in this instance I'm keen to discover why it _doesn't_ happen.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Sorry, I thought it was obvious from Nawaz' answer. I detailed the reason in a proper answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is simple. If you read the question I asked about:

> [std::ostringstream printing the address of the c-string instead of its content.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287188/stdostringstream-printing-the-address-of-the-c-string-instead-of-its-content)

you will note that the trick to getting a "proper" reference instead of a temporary is to call a method on the object (not restricted to the not binding restriction for some reason) that will return a reference.

In Nawaz's answer above, he called `std::ostream& std::ostream::flush()`, in your case here:

```
std::ostringstream() << 0 << "hi"
```

you call `std::ostringstream& std::ostringstream::operator<<(int)`.

Same result.

The surprising behavior is due to `ostream` mishmash implementations: some `operator<<` are member methods while others are free-functions.

You can test it, simply, by implementing an `X& ref()` method on an object:

```
struct X { X& ref(); };

void call(X& x);

int main() {
    call(X{});       // error: cannot bind X& to a temporary
    call(X{}.ref()); // OK
}
```

**EDIT**: but why is not `X&` (the result of `ref`) treated the same ?

It is a matter of [classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues). A temporary is a `prvalue` whilst a reference is a `lvalue`. A reference is only allowed to bind to a `lvalue`.

Of course since methods can be called on `rvalue` (and thus `prvalue`) and those methods may return a reference to the objects they were called on we can easily bypass the silly (1) *a reference is only allowed to bind to a `lvalue`* restriction...

(1) it's also inconsistent with the fact that a `rvalue` can be bound to a const-reference.

Comment: I don't feel that this answers the question. I know about the member function and the free function. But the object is still a temporary, so why does the reference bind to it in the end just because it has been produced by a function call?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: a simple `lvalue`/`rvalue` issue, I extended my answer. How could the compiler know that `X& X::ref()` is the one `X` instance that `ref` is called on ? It cannot (in general), so it's purely based on classification of types.

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't the reference on the LHS still a temporary?

It is a lvalue reference to a temporary (the return value), which is still a lvalue and so can bind to lvalue references.

Think of temporaries in terms of lifetime rather than l/rvalueness.

Comment: (you probably knew this. I am confused to what you are asking :S)